# Cannot resolve method put(java.lang.string, java.lang.string)

Tags: java, android

I am following a solution placed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258791/3358664), and getting a Cannot resolve method put(java.lang.string, java.lang.string)  I am attempting to avert to avert losing the data in my webview on orientation change without handling the orientation change manually.

my code is posted below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webcontent);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Welcome.html");
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getApplicationContext().
            getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.put("lastUrl",myWebView.getUrl());
    edit.commit();   // can use edit.apply() but in this case commit is better
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(myWebView != null) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getApplicationContext().
                getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String s = prefs.getString("lastUrl","");
        if(!s.equals("")) {
            myWebView.loadUrl(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how about using putString? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: There's no such type as `java.lang.string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editor doesn't contain a method "put".

Because you want to put an url, you can use Editor.putString instead

So there you go

```
edit.putString("lastUrl",myWebView.getUrl());
```

Comment: Yes it is, on developer.android 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

There's no put methods for SharedPreferences.Editor.
The correct one should be

```
edit.putString("lastUrl",myWebView.getUrl());
```

You can find out more here [SharedPreferences.Editor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)